# Javascript Tic Tac Toe Win Checker is Wet

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, tic-tac-toe

New to coding/Javascript. Writing a basic Tic Tac Toe game.

I'm writing the game to be dynamic, so it won't always be a three-by-three grid, but rather any size grid larger than 1. I have a completely functioning game and win checker function, but the win checker is very, very wet. I've tried several way to dry it up, but can't really find a good pattern that doesn't cause bugs or issues.

The winChecker function below receives a 2D array that could resemble something like (for a 3x3 grid):

```js
const squares = [
  [null, null, null],
  [null, null, null],
  [null, null, null]
];
```

The winChecker function looks like:

```js
const winChecker = squares => {
  for (let column = 0; column < squares.length; column++) {
    const horizontalCase = squares[column][0];
    const verticalCase = squares[0][column];
    const negativeCase = squares[0][0];
    const positiveCase = squares[0][squares.length - 1];
    if (horizontalCase !== null) {
      for (let row = 0; row < squares.length; row++) {
        if (horizontalCase !== squares[column][row]) {
          break;
        } else {
          if (row === squares.length - 1) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    if (verticalCase !== null) {
      for (let row = 0; row < squares.length; row++) {
        if (verticalCase !== squares[row][column]) {
          break;
        } else {
          if (row === squares.length - 1) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    if (negativeCase !== null) {
      for (let row = 0; row < squares.length; row++) {
        if (negativeCase !== squares[row][row]) {
          break;
        } else {
          if (row === squares.length - 1) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    if (positiveCase !== null) {
      for (let row = 0; row < squares.length; row++) {
        if (positiveCase !== squares[row][squares.length - 1 - row]) {
          break;
        } else {
          if (row === squares.length - 1) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
```

The function above actually works, it's just real wet. Any help in drying it up would be really appreciated!

Comment: If it works but you need to improve it, then head over to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code works. It should be asked on Code Review instead.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is decouple the logic for selecting the cells to be checked from the checking itself.

Checking if a row/column/diagonal is all the same values can boil down to logic iterating over an iterable:

```js
function getGroupWinner(iterable) {
  let winner = undefined;
  for (const value of iterable) {
    if (winner === undefined) winner = value;
    if (value !== winner) return null;
  }
  return winner;
}
```

...and selecting the groups to check could look something like

```js
// Assume `grid` is a square array of arrays...
function *getWinnableGroups(grid) {
  const length = grid.length;
  const indexes = [...grid.keys()];
  const opposite = idx => length - idx - 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    yield grid[i];                      // Row i
    yield indexes.map(j => grid[j][i]); // Column i
  }

  // Diagonals
  yield indexes.map(i => grid[i][i]);
  yield indexes.map(i => grid[i][opposite(i)])
}
```

This now gives you an arguably elegant core logic for checking results:

```js
function winChecker(squares) {
  for (const group of getWinnableGroups(squares)) {
    const winner = getGroupWinner(group);
    if (winner) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jacob! Yeah, that definitely helps clean it up. Didn't even think about using a generator function!